# Vue.js v-for add to :index + "1"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lightbox

I need add to every my index word +1 in v-for rendering list.
for example first list index0, second index1, third index2...in my option imageIndex is that string which i need add to every index

is this anyway possible? or how can i create for every v-rendered image in list lightbox gallery

here is my code:

```
<div class="m-3" v-for="(item, imageIndex) in info" :key="item.id">
<CoolLightBox
  :items = "[result[imageIndex]]"
  :index= "index"  // here i need add to index +1 every time ...index0, index1, index2
  @close= "index = null">  // here i need add to index +1 every time ...index0, index1, index2
</CoolLightBox>

<img
    class="img-thumbnail"
    @click="index = imageIndex" // here i need add to index +1 every time ...index0, index1, index2
    :src= "[result[imageIndex]]">
</div>


export default {
  components: {
    CoolLightBox
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      result: [
        'static/m/954.jpg',
        'static/m/955.jpg',
        'static/m/956.jpg'
      ],
      index: null
    }
  }
}
```

i try something like this

```
<CoolLightBox
        :items = "[result[0]]"
        :index= "`index${imageIndex}`"
        @close= "`index${imageIndex}` = null">
</CoolLightBox>
```

but its not working for me

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
:index = "'index' + imageIndex"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the exact example in the official docs found here: https://vue-cool-lightbox.lucaspulliese.com/

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <CoolLightBox 
      :items="items" 
      :index="index"
      @close="index = null">
    </CoolLightBox>

    <div class="images-wrapper">
      <div
        class="image"
        v-for="(image, imageIndex) in items"
        :key="imageIndex"
        @click="index = imageIndex"
        :style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + image + ')' }"
      ></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: yes I know but it don`t help me....what i need to create multiple galleries on page? unique :index?

Comment: Multiple galeries ? Like several lightboxes ? Not sure on what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: yes i want to create for every image one lightbox, so when user click on image it open only in lightbox,,,,not as a gallery

Comment: Like this kind of stuff ? (click on landscape or cat photo) https://medium-zoom.francoischalifour.com/

Comment: yes, something like that,,,but probably it is unnecessarily create for every my picture "single image gallery - with one picture" ...this will be probably better soluton for me

Comment: Yep, `vue-cool-lightbox` is not the right package for this purpose. Want me to make an example on how to make the "medium-zoom" example ?

Comment: thanks! I already have it done with it, really thank you very much :)
here is a vue.js example: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/francoischalifour/medium-zoom/tree/master/examples/vue?file=/index.html:356-383

Comment: Alright, I wanted to show you how to do it to achieve an accepted answer...but I guess that I still helped you fixing your issue. Glad it works ! :)

Comment: i have one little problem with medium-zoom, if i use pagination it not working correct. when I am on first page it working well but on second I have to click two times for close image on third I have to click 3 times on fourth 4 times...its problem with index or what?

Comment: Depends on how/where you import the package and the event listeners that you plugged between the pages. Will need to inspect the components themselves here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66274853/medium-zoom-pagination-issues here is a new Question if you have a little time, thanks :)