# medium-zoom pagination issues

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pagination

In my project I use [medium-zoom](https://github.com/francoischalifour/medium-zoom)  with pagination. On first page it works well but on second, third, fourth... I have to click several times for close image...on second page...two times, on third 3 times...
it seems to be a problem with maybe any index number?

Here is my code:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="loading" class="text-center">
      <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-5x"></i>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <div v-for="(item, imageIndex) in pageOfItems" :key="item.id" class="m-3">
        <div class="row mt-3">
          <div class="col-lg-9 my-auto" v-html="item.mytext"></div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 my-auto text-center">
            <article class="container">
              <img
                class="img-thumbnail"
                :src="'http://localhost:4000/api/galeria/' + item.galeriaId + '_f.jpg'"
              />
            </article>
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr class="hr1" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pb-0 pt-3 text-center">
      <jw-pagination :items="info" :page-size="10" @changePage="onChangePage"></jw-pagination>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import mediumZoom from 'medium-zoom'
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      info: [],
      customLabels,
      pageOfItems: [],
      loading: true,
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:4000/api/fetch_galeria.php/')
      .then((response) => (this.info = response.data))
      .finally(() => (this.loading = false))
  },
  updated() {
    mediumZoom('article img', {
      background: 'transparent',
    })
  },
  methods: {
    onChangePage(pageOfItems) {
      // update page of items
      this.pageOfItems = pageOfItems
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: As always, a code reproduction is welcome for all the people around here. :D On a side note, be careful of the `v-html` directive and prefer to use a sanitizer instead, to avoid XSS: https://github.com/LeSuisse/vue-dompurify-html

Answer (score 0):

You will pretty much need to [`detach`](https://github.com/francoischalifour/medium-zoom#detachselectors-string--htmlelement--nodelist--array-zoom) the event listeners here. Because it should be a lot of them added everytime due to the `updated` hook.

A naive implementation would be to add `mediumZoom` on the `mounted` hook. And when you do have a new `changePage` event, to detach it from all the images, then to apply it to the new ones with the same `mediumZoom` call.

Below is a way to see which event listeners (and probably how many) you have linked to a specific VueJS component. Select it in the Vue devtools and then, you will have access to the element's properties via `$vm0`.

[image]